# Bind Exception when trying to send UDP packet

Tags: java, sockets, exception

I am making a peer to peer chat application for which I have written the below code for chat with one person. This code works for localhost(127.0.0.1) but doesn't work for any specific ip address(192.168.43.118) and throws bindexception. Please help.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class communicate {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        communicate ob = new communicate();
        String ip = "192.168.43.118";
        ob.text(ip);
    }
    public void text(String friend_ip) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Press 'Exit' to exit the chat");
        int send_port = 40002;
        int receive_port = 40002;
        //InetAddress inetaddr = InetAddress.getByName(friend_ip);
        byte[] ipAddr = new byte[] { (byte)192, (byte)168, (byte)43, (byte)118 };
        System.out.println(ipAddr.length);
        InetAddress inetaddr = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddr);
        System.out.println("B");
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(receive_port, inetaddr);
        System.out.println("YO");
        Runnable send = new SendMsg(send_port, friend_ip, serverSocket);
        Runnable receive = new GetMsg(friend_ip, receive_port, serverSocket);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(send);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(receive);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    class SendMsg implements Runnable {
        private DatagramSocket senderSocket;
        private int send_port;
        private String sendto_ip;
        SendMsg(int port, String friend_ip, DatagramSocket ds)throws Exception {
            senderSocket = new DatagramSocket(64432);
            send_port = port;
            sendto_ip = friend_ip;
        }
        public void run(){
            try {
                while(true) {
                String sendString;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                sendString = br.readLine();
                byte[] sendData = sendString.getBytes();
                byte[] ipAddr = new byte[] { (byte)192, (byte)168, (byte)43, (byte)118 };
                InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddr);
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket (sendData, sendData.length, inetAddress, send_port);
                senderSocket.send(sendPacket);
                System.out.println("Message Sent");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exc at Sender\n" + e);
            }
            finally {
                if(senderSocket != null) senderSocket.close();
            }
        }

    }

    class GetMsg implements Runnable{
        private DatagramSocket serverSocket;
        private String friend_ip;
        private int receive_port;

        GetMsg(String ip, int port, DatagramSocket ds) throws Exception{
            friend_ip = ip;
            receive_port = port;
            serverSocket = ds;
        }
        public void run(){
            try {
                while(true) {
                byte[] receiveData = new byte[10000];
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                String message = new String (receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());
                System.out.println(friend_ip + ": " + message);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exc at Rec\n" + e);
            }
            finally {
                if(serverSocket != null) serverSocket.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it on terminal the following output is shown

```
Press 'Exit' to exit the chat
4
B
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address (Bind failed)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:131)
        at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:394)
        at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:244)
        at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:301)
        at communicate.text(communicate.java:21)
        at communicate.main(communicate.java:10)
```

As "YO" is not printed it seems that error is in the text method where I am trying to create DatagramSocket. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are trying to bind to a non-local IP address. Why you're consuming three sockets and only actually using two of them remains a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want read, do not bind the remote address. Just create a local UDP socket (it will be a server socket) and just read from/write to its buffer. You can bind to your local network interface only and these must be initialized before. So you cannot bind to an unused Wifi, or unplugged ethernet adapter.

If you want test a sender, and a receiver in the same java program on different threads, you have to use two different socket.

A hint: use [`InetAddress.getByName(IPv4)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String)) for string IP input, you do not need the byte array.